# Map strings of letters and numbers based on if there's a valid date

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have 5 strings:

```
MO170915C00075000

GILD1514H117

9ZZZFD898

AHMIQ

894990415
```

The first two have valid dates between between the first set of numbers and then then the next single letter (ex: C).

If I may ask, how would pick out the first two strings due to the date that's in them (need to identify that they contain a date after the first set of letters and before a single character) and then correctly format the dates?

For the first one, I can get the date using the GSub below:

```
("20" + @ticker.gsub(/(\w+?)(\d{6})([a-z])\d+/i,'\2')).to_date
```

Comment: What's the definition of **valid dates**?

Comment: Is `11115` a valid date? Is it the `1 Nov 15` or `11 Jan 15`? Or is it just to extract numbers that are surrounded by characters?

Comment: There is no method `String#to_date` in ruby.

Comment: I've downvoted because the question is unclear (what is the date in `"GILD1514H117"`?) and because you've seen @Aetherus' question but chose not to answer it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - It's 5am here, so I apologize as I was asleep... I don't know why you've made the assumption that I saw his answer over an hour ago.

Comment: @Aetherus - The date for the first one (i.e. MO170915C00075000) should be 2017-9-15 and the Gsub that I included takes it out in that format. The second one (i.e. GILD1514H117) is  2015-01-04. By valid dates, I mean there is no date that can be obtained from "9ZZZFD898" or "894990415".

Comment: Please edit the question to incorporate the information in your last comment. (You cannot rely on readers reading all comments.) Once you do so I will remove my downvote. (SO prevents me from changing my vote unless the question is edited. I assumed you saw @Aetherus' comment because it was posted before you were last seen on SO (the latter from your profile). Perhaps that wasn't correct.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Feel free not to remove it.

Comment: What is the date in "GILD15111H117", "2015-11-1" or "2015-1-11"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Great question! I honestly don't know, so I really appreciate you pointing that out. You made an extremely strong case that I'll have to build a feature to flag strings that could contain multiple dates, and ask the user to choose which one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Date._parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse) to see which information could be found by [`Date.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse).

Without any specification, you'll be basically shooting in the dark. Since the logic is so fuzzy, it cannot work magically with any weird string as input :

```
require 'date'
weird_dates = %w(MO170915C00075000 MA20172115C00075000 GILD1514H117 9ZZZFD898 AHMIQ 894990415)

weird_dates.each do |date_str|
  date_hash = Date._parse(date_str)
  puts date_str
  puts "  #{date_hash}"
  if date_hash[:year] && date_hash[:mon] && date_hash[:mday]
    print "  It looks like a date"
    begin
      date = Date.parse(date_str)
      puts " : #{date}"
    rescue ArgumentError
      puts " but it's not a valid one!"
    end
  else
    puts "  Sorry, not enough information"
  end
  puts
end
```

It outputs :

```
MO170915C00075000
  {:year=>2017, :mon=>9, :mday=>15}
  It looks like a date : 2017-09-15

MA20172115C00075000
  {:year=>2017, :mon=>21, :mday=>15}
  It looks like a date but it's not a valid one!

GILD1514H117
  {:hour=>1514, :min=>117}
  Sorry, not enough information

9ZZZFD898
  {:yday=>898}
  Sorry, not enough information

AHMIQ
  {}
  Sorry, not enough information

894990415
  {}
  Sorry, not enough information
```

If you know the exact input format, you should use [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. I didn't know that `Date._parse` could return out of range values.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
require 'date'

def extract_dates(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |str,a|
    s = str[/\d+/] || ''
    a <<
    case s.size
    when 8
      [convert_to_time(s, 4, 2, 2)]
    when 7
      [convert_to_time(s, 4, 2, 1), convert_to_time(s, 4, 1, 2)]
    when 6
      [convert_to_time(s, 4, 1, 1), convert_to_time(s, 2, 2, 2)]
    when 5
      [convert_to_time(s, 2, 2, 1), convert_to_time(s, 2, 1, 2)]
    when 4
      [convert_to_time(s, 2, 1, 1)]
    else
      []
    end.compact
  end
end

def convert_to_time(s, y, m, d)
  ss = s.dup
  ss.insert(0, "20") if y == 2
  ss.insert(4, "0") if m == 1
  ss.insert(6, "0") if d == 1
  DateTime.strptime(ss, "%Y%m%d") rescue nil
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = <<-_.split
MA170915C00075000
MA20170915C00075000
MA20172115C00075000
GILD1514H117
GILD15111H117
9ZZZFD898
AHMIQ
894990415
_
  #=> ["MA170915C00075000", "MA20170915C00075000", "MA20172115C00075000",
  #    "GILD1514H117", "GILD15111H117", "9ZZZFD898", "AHMIQ", "894990415"] 

arr.zip(extract_dates arr)
  #=> [["MA170915C00075000",
  #      [#<DateTime: 1709-01-05T00:00:00+00:00 ((2345264j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #       #<DateTime: 2017-09-15T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458012j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]],
  #    ["MA20170915C00075000",
  #      [#<DateTime: 2017-09-15T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458012j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]],
  #    ["MA20172115C00075000", []],
  #    ["GILD1514H117",
  #      [#<DateTime: 2015-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457027j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]],
  #    ["GILD15111H117",
  #      [#<DateTime: 2015-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457328j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #       #<DateTime: 2015-01-11T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457034j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]],
  #    ["9ZZZFD898", []],
  #    ["AHMIQ", []],
  #    ["894990415", []]]
```

This shows that:

- the first string of digits in "MA170915C00075000", "170915", can be interpreted as one of two dates, "1709-1-5" and "2017-09-15".
- the first digits in "MA20170915C00075000", "20170915", can be interpreted as one date only, "2017-09-15".
- the first digits in "MA20172115C00075000", "20172115", do not represent a valid date, so  an empty array is returned.
- the first digits in "GILD15111H117", "15111", could represent the date "2015-11-01" or "2015-01-11".